# "We are planned for audit on Friday" vs. "We planned for audit on Friday"

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please let me know the difference between these two sentences?

> We are planned for audit on Friday.
>
> We planned for audit on Friday.

Which one is correct, or are both wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We can plan an audit. The audit can be planned by us. The audit can be planned by someone else. But we are not planned; we (or they) are the planners. We are not the thing that is planned. We can be *ready* for the audit that is planned for Friday.

Answer (score 0):

Both are wrong, in that they are missing an **an** before audit.

Both are also wrong in grammar.

It should be

> "We have an audit planned on Friday."

Comment: I think this works as well: "We have an audit planned for Friday." What do you say?

Comment: @KinzleB Yep, that's good too.